# Year Function in R

Tags: r

I am getting an error message

```
datacfs_date$FeedbackMonth<-paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),sep="")


Error in paste(year(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate), "-M", month(datacfs_date$FeedbackDate),: 
could not find function "year".
```

Do i need to import a package or something ?

Comment: Please try to actually ask a question if you expect to get an answer. Simply saying "I am getting an error message" doesn't really show us much effort from your side.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to format a date.  There's probably a way to do that directly without using `year` or `month` functions.  What class is `datacfs_date$FeedbackDate`?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - "*It looks like you're trying to format a date*" - are you [Clippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the lubridate package that might do what you seem to be looking for..
Here is an example with today's date from `now()`

```
library(lubridate)
year(now())
month(now())
paste(year(now()), '-M', month(now(), label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE) sep="")
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why you would want the `M` in the result.